# is "the gift of" an equivalence for "by the permission of"?

Tags: meaning

Needless to say that in the context of copy right issues, the phrase "the courtesy of somebody" means "by the permission of somebody" (in image captions). My question is that does "the gift of somebody" also has the same meaning and regularity?

For example, the "image credits" section at the bottom of a museum page like the [Frye Art Museum](http://fryemuseum.org/exhibition/71/) shows that most of the images are "a gift of somebody" (my emphases):

> - Collection American Folk Art Museum, New York, **gift of** Nathan and Kiyoko Lerner, 1995.23.1b. ©Kiyoko Lerner. Photo by Gavin Ashworth
> - Collection American Folk Art Museum, New York, **gift of** Nathan and Kiyoko Lerner, 1995.23.1a. ©Kiyoko Lerner. Photo by Gavin Ashworth
> - Collection American Folk Art Museum, New York, **gift of** Robert and Luise Kleinberg in celebration of granddaughter Cecelia Cooley, with Kiyoko Lerner, 2004.15.1. ©Kiyoko Lerner. Photo by James Prinz
> - Collection American Folk Art Museum, New York, museum purchase and gift, 2002.22.1a. ©Kiyoko Lerner. Photo by James Prinz

Comment: *Gift of* here has its usual meaning of describing who made the gift of the painting to the Museum. The painting is owned by the Museum because it was given by its donor; the *gift of* designation shows who the donor was. It's a slightly softer way of saying *Given by*. (I'll leave explaining the construction itself to someone else!)

Comment: "gift of" implies the ownership of the particular painting or art works has been transferred from a giver to a receiver. In absolute contrast to "gift", "courtesy" implies the right has been permitted probably for a certain amount of money for a certain period for usage. If "gift" is used, I don't think there is a commercial transaction involved. It was given for "free"

Comment: As Andrew says, the items were given to the the American Folk Art Museum by the identified parties.  This is largely unrelated to the subsequent granting of image rights by the museum, but is apparently a common courtesy in the museum world.